# For loop fails, but code appears to be correct

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

My code looks fine to me, but I'm getting a syntax error in my for loop. Does anyone know why this would be the case? I've included my code below:

```
def printLine(numberOfDots):
    dots = 0
    for x in range numberOfDots:
        dots += 1
    printDots = print("." * dots)
    return printDots

printLine(20)
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image (and definitely not as a link to an image).

Comment: Somehow, the image linked looks as if it has been edited to be less readable than an ordinary screenshot...

Comment: I could not get the Python interpreter to run the image that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

`range` is a function, so you should use `range(numberOfDots)` instead of `range numberOfDots`.

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Since you never explained what it is supposed to do, I'm afraid I can't be of much help.